# error in eval(predvars data env) object age not found

Tags: object, error-handling

I keep getting this error and I am unsure as to why. I've tried to diagnose but "age" works just fine up to this particular chunk, so I'm stumped. Can anyone see the issue?

These are the only other instances where I've used "age"

```
df <- dplyr::select(df,age,ag16g10,Sex,Ethnic05,GenHelf,BMI_SR,HadCovid,RecVacB,VacOff,Vaccine,Vacwill,hedqul08,VitTake,VitaminD,SmokEver,PregNTJ)
```

```
df <- filter(df,age >= 18, age <= 98)
```

And here is where the error keeps getting thrown up at me, when I was trying to test my model:

```
df %>%
  lm(lm(BMI_SR ~ RecVacB + Vacwill + Sex + ag16g10 + Ethnic05 + hedqul08 + HadCovid + GenHelf + VitTake + SmokEver, data = df) %>%
  plot(which = 1))
```